# Conditional formatting based on non-specific text in adjacent cell

Tags: conditional-formatting

I want to format values in one column based on whether or not any text or letters appear in the adjacent column.  (the letters are being used for significance testing.) How would I indicate *any text* in the formula?

Comment: Never mind -- I got it.  The term is "ISTEXT".  So my formula was: =ISTEXT(B12)